# Как сохранить css свойство на jQuery перед изменением?

Tags: jquery

У меня есть вот такой код.

```
var topi = parseInt($('.test2').css("top")); 
$(window).scroll(function(f) {
var s = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.test2').css('top',   s+topi);       
});
```

И мне нужно сохранить значение topi перед изменением так что бы.

Было например: top=s+topi, top=1+150, top=2+150, top=3+150.

А не так top=1+150, top=2+151, top=3+153.

Answer (score 0):

Запишите в data атрибут элемента

```
var topi = parseInt($('.test2').css("top")); 
$('.test2').data('topi', topi )
```